# GEarthView plugin doesn't work

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to install the GEarthView plugin but without success. The following message pops up after installation:

"No module named zope.interface"

What is the problem?

QGIS 2.6.0
Windows7 (64Bit)

Comment: Following error now occur: ![QGIS 2.8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9lQcx.jpg) Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, you need to copy

zope
twisted

inside the QGIS path. For example:

QGIS Brighton\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\twisted\
QGIS Brighton\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zope\

Comment: When you say copy, what do you mean? There are 4 files to download on the twisted repository, for example. One is a Windows installation file which does nothing. Do we just download one of the others and copy it into those folders?

Answer (score 2):

There is a big advice `Install, before, the following python libraries: twisted\ Twisted-13.0.0-py2.7-win32 ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted/13.0.0 ) zope\ zope.interface-3.6.0-py2.7-win32 ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface/3.6.0 )`in the plugin window.

Unfortunately, there is no package of zope.interface-3.6.0 for Python 2.7, which QGIS uses. You may try newer versions of zope.interface that support Python 2.7 as well:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface/3.6.7

up to

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface/4.1.2

See also https://github.com/geodrinx/gearthview/issues/1

Comment: No, sorry. The zope installation needs python 2.6. I'm using 2.7. I tried to install the 2.6.6. But after the installation the zope installation can't find Python 2.6